# Duplicate rows while multiplying two columns of two different tables using joins

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have these following tables

1. Question_Segment_Master
2. Question_Set_Details

While I am joining these two tables I am getting duplicate rows..
Please view fiddle,where I posted those twos schema and it's data..

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/4c84f/10

This is my expected OP

[image]

Comment: sqlfiddle is great, but add the table data, the expected result, and the query here too.

Comment: I have posted there sir

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't show duplicate rows, please explain what you consider "duplicate"

Comment: I am joining with 2 tables and in where clause I have mentioned conditions , still I am getting duplicate segment id(s) where it needs to be distinct..

Comment: Well, your sqlfiddle shows 3 rows with 3 different values for `segment_id`, so i have to quote @HoneyBadger. Where is your duplicate?

Comment: Maybe you have forgotten to use segment_id in the JOIN?  Please paste here the expected result table.

Comment: please review my question again.. I have posted screenshot of expecting output.

Comment: In your expected output picture, you have the same data as fiddle result with just lesser columns

Comment: may be you forgot to have this on joinn `and qsd.segment_id = qsm.segment_id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the question_marks of each segment. Also, you should JOIN using the branch_id, test_id, subject_code_id along with the segment_id.

Using JOIN and then take Distinct values

```
SELECT DISTINCT qsm.segment_id, segment_name, segment_description
  , must_attend_question AS tot_attented_question, total_question AS tot_questions
  , (qsd.question_marks * must_attend_question) AS tot_marks
  , '' AS marks_obtain
FROM dbo.Question_Segment_Master AS qsm
INNER JOIN dbo.Question_Set_Details AS qsd
ON (qsd.branch_id = qsm.branch_id AND qsd.test_id = qsm.test_id
AND qsd.segment_id = qsm.segment_id AND qsd.subject_code_id = qsm.subject_code_id)
WHERE qsm.subject_code_id = 1 and qsm.test_id = 1 and qsm.branch_id = 15;
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/4c84f/34)

Answer (score 1):

You were missing the segment_id in your join clause

```
SELECT DISTINCT
        qsm.segment_id,
        qsm.segment_name,
        qsm.segment_description,
        qsm.must_attend_question tot_attented_question,
        qsm.total_question tot_questions,
        (qsd.question_marks * must_attend_question) tot_marks,
        '' AS marks_obtain
FROM dbo.question_segment_master qsm 
INNER JOIN dbo.question_set_details qsd on
                                        qsd.test_id = qsm.test_id
                                        and qsd.segment_id = qsm.segment_id
WHERE qsm.test_id=1
      AND qsm.branch_id = 15 
      AND qsm.subject_code_id =1 AND qsd.question_set_id = 1
```